# Bash: generate lines with characters at given positions

Tags: bash

Given a list of numbers generate lines with a single X if the line number is in the list of numbers, and a single underscore otherwise.

Input:

```
2
3
5
```

output

```
_
X
X
_
X
```

The input is sorted always sorted. I need it to be a short Bash snipped, preferably a nice one liner

**Background**

I do a small extension to VIM to mark some lines. The VIM input is an output from `grep -n <pattern> <input> | cut -f1 -d:` (or other command with similar output). I need to generate the lines to later present them in VIM.

Answer (score 3):

Using sed to generate a sed script to be used by sed on an output of seq:

```
#! /bin/bash
input=PATH/TO/INPUT/FILE
seq 1 $(tail -n1 $input) | sed -n -f <(sed -e 's/$/{cX\nb}/;$ac_' $input)
```

Answer (score 2):

awk:

```
printf "%d\n" 2 3 5 | 
awk '{x[$1]} END {for(i=1; i<=$1; i++) print (i in x) ? "X" : "_"}'
```

In the END block, I use `$1` from the last line read. As you indicate, this will be the maximum number.

Answer (score 1):

Very ugly and inefficient solution but the shortest I could think of right now ;)

Assuming you have the numbers in a file called `test.txt`:

```
for i in $(seq $(tail -n 1 test.txt)); do grep -q "^$i$" test.txt && echo X || echo _; done
```